# Eclipse not showing wsdl options

Tags: eclipse, wsdl

I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (Link: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/mars1) using the 64 bit.

I want to 'connect' to a wsdl from Eclipse. I have followed several guides on the internet, but the problem is that my Eclipse doesn't show same options. When I launch web services explorer in Eclipse, the left column shows "UDDI Main" then I press WSDL page in the upper right corner, and the left column still only shows UDDI Main, not WSDL as all the tutorials on the internet says I should click.

Any suggestions on what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the Web Service Explorer's toolbar (top-right), click on the WSDL Page icon,